# Magic The Gathering Mysql table how to call a function within an echo that is within a php script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, function

How do you put php within php? The script below is where I am trying to place the php within the php script. Near the bottom for the function boutique_product_name. That line of code has two separate instances of calling functions but it must nest within this mysql table. I've omitted alot of the code that was not necessary to display so it would be easier to follow. But it will eventually be a mysql table pulled from an xml file for magic the gathering cards. Which will include pricing data and the ability to buy the cards hence which is what the functions at the bottom are for.

I will still need to figure out how to make actual product pages for each card within the table but that's for later.

So if anyone knows how in the world to place a

```
<?php
    $z = new xmlreader;
    $z->open('http://*****.com/wp-content/themes/*****/mtg/arb.xml'); // Your XML File name
    $doc = new DOMDocument;

    while ($z->read() && $z->name !== 'card');
    echo "<table border=1>
    <tr></tr>";

    while ($z->name === 'card')
    {
        $node = new SimpleXMLElement($z->readOuterXML());

        echo "<tr>

        <td><div class='id1'>".$node->id."</div></td>
        <td><div class='cardname1'>".$node->name."</div></td>
        <td><div class='set1'>".$node->set."</div></td>
        <td><div class='cardtype1'>".$node->type."</div></td>
        <td><div class='rarity1'>".$node->rarity."</div></td>
        <td><div class='manacost1'>".$node->manacost."</div></td>

        $id     =   $node->id;
        $name       =   $node->name;
        $set        =   $node->set;
        $type       =   $node->type;
        $rarity     =   $node->rarity;
        $manacost   =   $node->manacost;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `*****_wrdp2`.`cards` 

        (`id`, `name`, `set`, `type`, `rarity`, `mana cost`) 
        VALUES 
        ('$id', '$name', '$set', '$type', '$rarity', '$manacost');";

        if(mysql_query($sql)) 
        {
            echo "<td><div class='error'><font color='green'><b>Success!</b></font></div></td></tr>";

            } else {

            echo "<td><div class='error'><font color='red'><b>Failure! (".mysql_error().")</b></font></div></td></tr>";
        }

        echo "<a href="#<?php echo boutique_product_name('offer'); ?>" class="add-to-cart et-shop-item"><?php esc_html_e('Add to cart','Boutique'); ?></a>";
        $z->next('card');
    }

    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you are looking for "eval", but I don't think that is really what you want. You seem to be passing in the same argument to the function every time. If this is done well, then the same input should result in the same output.

Can't you just call:

```
 $prodName = boutique_product_name('offer');

 while ($z->name === 'card')
{
    $node = new SimpleXMLElement($z->readOuterXML());

    echo "<tr>

    <td><div class='id1'>".$node->id."</div></td>
    <td><div class='cardname1'>".$node->name."</div></td>
    <td><div class='set1'>".$node->set."</div></td>
    <td><div class='cardtype1'>".$node->type."</div></td>
    <td><div class='rarity1'>".$node->rarity."</div></td>
    <td><div class='manacost1'>".$node->manacost."</div></td>";
    // notice that close quote!

    $id     =   $node->id;
    $name       =   $node->name;
    $set        =   $node->set;
    $type       =   $node->type;
    $rarity     =   $node->rarity;
    $manacost   =   $node->manacost;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `*****_wrdp2`.`cards` 

    (`id`, `name`, `set`, `type`, `rarity`, `mana cost`) 
    VALUES 
    ('$id', '$name', '$set', '$type', '$rarity', '$manacost');";

    if(mysql_query($sql)) 
    {
        echo "<td><div class='error'><font color='green'><b>Success!</b></font></div></td></tr>";

        } else {

        echo "<td><div class='error'><font color='red'><b>Failure! (".mysql_error().")</b></font></div></td></tr>";
    }

    // note the escapes
    echo "<a href=\"#$prodName\" class=\"add-to-cart et-shop-item\"><?php esc_html_e('Add to cart','Boutique'); ?></a>";
    $z->next('card');
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wasn't thinking of!  Got it in the right place, like so:  echo "<td><a href=\"#$prodName\" class=\"add-to-cart et-shop-item\">\"$esc_html_e\"</a></td>"; now the hard part of figuring out how to make each card in the tables automatically create a product page for each